# Rails Database Structure Advice?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I need to make a website structure in rails in which there are administrators, workers, and clients. The administrators need to have control over everything and be able to view everything, workers need to have control over just the clients and be able to view all the clients information, and clients have no control over anything, but can view their own data.

Whats the best way to accomplish this?

I was thinking about making an administrator model which `has_many :workers` and `has_many :clients` and then creating a worker model which `has_many :clients` and `belongs_to :administrator` and then creating a client model which `belongs_to :worker`. Is this the most efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way is make `User` and `Role` models. Then add some authentification gem like [devise](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise) and also autorization gem like [cancan](https://github.com/ryanb/cancan) where you can setup abilities for specific roles.

in your case

```
class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end

class User < ActiveRecord::Base 
  belongs_to :role
end

class Ablility
  include CanCan::Ability  

  def initialize(user) 
    case user.role.name.to_sym
    when :admin          
      can :manage, :all
    when :worker
      can :manage, User, :role => { :name => 'client' }
    when :client
      can :read, User, :user_id => user.id
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: will this work even if i want administrators and workers to log into a different looking system than the clients?

Comment: different looking? you mean other design or other application

Comment: ok this makes sense. its gonna be a different design, not a different application. it'll just be different information required though for different users. thanks